# how to show progress of long running tasks from server on client side using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, rest, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api in the backend which would approve multiple invoices at a time. I set a flag saying approveAll=true, The API is async, it loops through the invoices and updates their status as APPROVED.

I have angular js application on the front end. I am using promise to call the API. This shouldn't block the UI right ?. I am using ngprogressbar to show the progress in angular js. The issue is the progressbar never gets completed, so the UI is blocked for a very long time.

How can I make the UI non blocking? Is there any way in angular js through which I can collect the progress count and show on the UI ?

Comment: Could you perhaps include some code to show how you are calling the back end and setting up / displaying the progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend ng-progress. This handles multiple requests and basically shows a neat little progress bar for all http activity.

[NgProgress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/)

You can use [Angular Loading Bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/). it suits for your

this is way we need to register Angular Loading Bar

```
angular.module('app', ['angular-loading-bar']);
```